# Precision, Recall, F1 Score and multiclass confusion matrix

Tags: precision-recall, confusion-matrix

My goal is to evaluate some clustering algorithms. Lets say that I’ve got one set o elements: { 1 ; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8 }. This set was grouped by human into two groups: (1 ; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 8) and (7). My automated clustering algorithm clustered those elements into clusters: (1; 2; 3; 7) and (4; 5; 6) and (8). Now I would like to calculate the Precision ( TP / (TP + FP) ), Recall ( TP / (TP + FN) ) and F1 Score ( 2 * (Precision * Recall) / (Precision + Recall) ).
My question is: how do I prepare the confusion matrix for this case, when number of groups provided by human differs from the number of predicted groups?

Comment: You are comparing two clusterings or a classification with a clustering. In this sort of comparison, the measures you talk about are computed based on _pairs_ of objects, and the confusion matrix for the pairs is 2x2. I recommend you to go to my webpage and read the document in zip called "Compare partitions".

Comment: I think that I'm comparing two clusterings: one made manually by human and second by automated algorithm. On both cases there is no knowledge about number of classes. objects are compared with each other by some similarity metric. Then, I want to compare the accuracy of automated algorithm with data provided by the human (which I am sure is the "golden" result).

Comment: So I have to prepare confusion matrix for each pair of elements, calculate for each pair precision, recall and F1 Score and then combine the result using for example the mean value?

Comment: No. (In my !cluagree function it is described). Irrespective of how many clusters there are the _comembership_ confusion matrix is always 2x2 (and one count therein is a _pair_ of objects out of N(N-1)/2 pairs. You are comparing cluster partitions, not classes.

Comment: Comparing a "true" (eg human) partition with a clustering partition is like comparing two clusterings - you don't know "correspondent" group labels in the two partitions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications! I’ve read document that you’ve suggested, and I think that now I understand. For the example provided in my question, I’ve calculated comembership confusion matrix: a = 6, b = 15, c = 3, d = 4. So: Precision ~= 0.67, Recall ~= 0.28, F1 = 0.4 . Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Now you are correct

Comment: Thanks! I've posted one more question regarding some differences I'm observing when calculating F-measure (as it was too long to post it here): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423404/calculating-f-measure-in-clusterings-comparison