# Calculating F-measure in clusterings comparison

Tags: clustering

In [“A comparison of Extrinsic Clustering Evaluation Metrics based on Formal Constraints Technical Report”](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Julio_Gonzalo/publication/225548032_Amigo_E_Gonzalo_J_Artiles_J_et_alA_comparison_of_extrinsic_clustering_evaluation_metrics_based_on_formal_constraints_Inform_Retriev_12461-486/links/0c96052138dbb99740000000/Amigo-E-Gonzalo-J-Artiles-J-et-alA-comparison-of-extrinsic-clustering-evaluation-metrics-based-on-formal-constraints-Inform-Retriev-12461-486.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=BVp5-cu12hNz0BrB9Jstgk_d8LpdMbhdL5uOE_ftkdtRBmpwbh6KQbF01DKGca87wgEaOkfDRYEcBayX9x2IGQ.bGbIvD_Ohtd-TcUi3gNjRvHm2oLy-qhuy9sQ7SeZRyOuZSf1zpEXmmxi5VrYR-zEzwP5d_uPAEz9nw-w_4AJNw&_sg%5B1%5D=F19xYSI3G3On97KihqlbmdQ64aGdnFyck-A7SJ-YGKAxjNnlJhI4bE5ltjIYEUCM438VJOrZ4EniRMTDSYPQA7_7yVQgbQoyxFZUbmYeSbj5.bGbIvD_Ohtd-TcUi3gNjRvHm2oLy-qhuy9sQ7SeZRyOuZSf1zpEXmmxi5VrYR-zEzwP5d_uPAEz9nw-w_4AJNw&_iepl=) on page 16 there is some simple example with metric results. According to the first column (cluster homogeneity), I’ve prepared 3 set of object:

```
1)  Golden result: (1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5), (6 ; 7 ; 8 ; 9 ; 10 ; 11), (12), (13), (14)
2)  Left set: (1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4), (5 ; 6 ; 7), (8 ; 9 ; 10 ; 11 ; 12 ; 13 ; 14)
3)  Right set: (1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4), (5), (6 ; 7), (8 ; 9 ; 10 ; 11 ; 12 ; 13 ; 14)
```

Then I’ve calculated for them (using information from ["Compare partitions"](http://www.spsstools.net/en/macros/KO-spssmacros/) document):

```
Rand: 1) and 2): 0.68, 1) and 3): 0.70
Jaccard: 1) and 2): 0.31, 1) and 3): 0.32
Folkes&Mallows: 1) and 2): 0.47, 1) and 3): 0.49
```

So everything is Exactly the same as in publication “A comparison of Extrinsic Clustering Evaluation Metrics based on Formal Constraints Technical Report”. But then I’ve calculated F-measure, and my result was:

```
1) and 2): 0.47 (in publication: 0.63)
1) and 3): 0.49 (in publication: 0.63)
```

Why am I observing differences?

Comment: I may confirm that your calculations are correct. Could be a typo there in the article, or could be (less likely) that they define F1 measure in an unusual way.

Comment: Note that all the four measures (Rand, Jaccard, F & M, F1) use the same 2x2 comembership confusion matrix entries. Therefore, if your computation of Rand, Jaccard, F & M are correct (and they are), F1 - using its usual formula - should also be correct, and your result was correct, for me.